# sparse coefficient time series models

Tags: time-series, arima, references, sparse

I am trying to build sparse coefficient time series  models but couldn't find a good resource/book to learn from.  Can anyone share with me a good resource/book?  It will be great if it comes with R codes.Can anyone use this kind model? Thanks.

Comment: Could you be a little more explicit as to what you mean by "sparse" in this context and how this differs from the Box-Jenkins approach?

Comment: For example:if we build an ARMA(p,q) model,generally,we need estimate p+q coefficients.The sparse means some of the p+q coefficients may equal to zero.So the model's coefficients are sparse.Maybe I don't describe clearly or in time-series these models don't call sparse coefficient models.If like this what they named? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the Lasso, Elastic Net and similar regularization techniques? The [Lasso](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_%28statistics%29#LASSO_method) specifically is used in regression with many regressors to yield a result where "many" cofficients are zero, which looks like what you are aiming for.

It looks like there is some interest out there in applying the Lasso and similar concepts to ARMA models. See, e.g., [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10425/fitting-an-arimax-model-with-regularization-or-penalization-e-g-with-the-lasso) or or [here](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Earinaldo/papers/arLasso.pdf).

I would recommend that you look into regularization and google for terms like "*regularization technique* *time series technique*".

Comment: I'd love to see an answer to the question posted at your first link... (http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10425/fitting-an-arimax-model-with-regularization-or-penalization-e-g-with-the-lasso)

Comment: @Zach: you and me both, it would make a lot of sense... But the paper behind my third link notes that simulations were done in R using `lars` and `glmnet`, so it might be worthwhile to mail the authors and ask for their code.

Comment: I failed to find the archived link of [this](http://www.intlpress.com/SII/p/2011/4-2/SII-4-2-a14-Chen.pdf) - this is not working any more @StephanKolassa.

Comment: @User1865345: thanks for pointing this out. I don't know which paper I referred to back then (thank goodness I have learned a bit about better linking in the last 10 years). Since I get a malware warning, I will remove the link from the answer.

Comment: Thanks @StephanKolassa for updating.