# ARMA: order selection with LASSO

Tags: forecasting, arima, lasso

I'm trying to forecast daily data (I have 15 years of historical data) with complex seasonality: weekly, monthly, annual and also irregular seasonality due to moving events like Easter. 
As suggested by  [Hyndman](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/dailydata/), I tried to use the `auto.arima()` function with covariates (Fourier Terms for regular seasonality; dummy variables for moving events). 
However, the multiple step-ahead forecasts for out of sample data are not good. 
Besides the `auto.arima()` function is very slow when including covariates.

I tried another approach:

1. Heuristically choose maximum lag orders for $p$, $q$, and the dummy variables for moving events;
2. Penalise the size of the coefficients (potentially all the way to zero) using LASSO.

The out of sample forecasts, both one-step ahead and multiple-steps ahead, are way better, and my code is running faster. 
But I'm not sure whether this approach make sense?

Comment: I believe you'll find your answer here https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/152202/240024

Comment: How do you implement LASSO ($L_1$) penalization for ARIMA with exogenous regressors or regression with ARMA errors? I am curious, because given that the error terms in the MA part of the model are unobserved, the problem is not a typical regression problem for which several LASSO algorithms exist.

Comment: @RichardHardy my mistake I posted to quickly => indeed in my alternative atempt I just have lags and dummy.

Comment: @Nutle, as far as I know, no one has done that, and given how simple/intuitive this is, there must be good reasons for that... See also my question linked in the comment above.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.