# LASSO algorithm for time series. R package available?

Tags: r, regression, time-series, lasso

I have a question for LASSO algorithm. From my understanding, LASSO algorithm can help me to determine among a lot of variables, which of them are useful and which of them are not, but existing LASSO regression method assumes independencies within variable. I want to apply this method on my analysis for time series and here's the task I need to perform:

I have 70 exogenous variables that are all continuous time series (for example, max / min air temperature, soil temperature, etc.), my target variable is groundwater head, which is also time series on a monthly basis, and I'd like to find out which one/ones of my exogenous variables can be predictive to my target variable. Within each exogenous variable, there might be a lagged effect, which can be up to 6 months, so in total I have 420 time series to predict my target variable. My response variable can also be predictive to itself, and can apply an AR(p) model on itself. I wonder if there is an R package that can do this kind of analysis?

Thanks a lot for your suggestions!

Comment: See [BigVAR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BigVAR/vignettes/BigVAR.html)

Comment: See also a related package ["bigtime"](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigtime/index.html) and a related question ["Regularization for ARIMA models"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152202).