# Cross validation for time series prediction: How to choose the best model from different neural networks?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, cross-validation, model-selection

I want to choose the best model from a list of neural network models. My problem is a multivariate time series forecast (regression) problem, in which I forecast a parameter using other parameters, up to 4 time steps ahead.

I have read [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14099/using-k-fold-cross-validation-for-time-series-model-selection) Q&A, but in that question, no practical way is presented to select the best model from a list of models.

After reading [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-nested-cross-validation-76adba623eb9) article, I decided to do the following procedure:

1. Create different neural network architectures.
2. Using the picture below, for each Neural Network (NN) architecture,
   perform 3 nested cross-validation (CV) . calculate *RMSE*s for each test data, and then calculate the average of these 3 *RMSE*s.

[image]

3. compare These average *RMSE*s of different architectures. The
   architecture with the lowest average *RMSE* is my best NN model.
4. Train the chosen architecture with all data.
5. predict and see the results of the trained model on my pre-reserved
   test data.

The author claims that this procedure makes an unbiased error. It
   refers to this line of ([Varma and Simon 2006](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1397873/))'s paper:

> A nested cross-validation procedure provides an almost unbiased
>   estimate of the true error.

To be honest, I have doubts that this nested CV is unbiased.

I have some questions:

- Is 3 nested CV enough? Maybe 5 is better?
- Does my procedure have any defections?
- How about using traditional K-Fold CV? Is it completely false?

Comment: Also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8807/cross-validating-time-series-analysis

Comment: @mkt,
 I think those question don't discuss about how to choose the best model based on the average of RMSE's and also the validity of this action itself. They just generally discuss about the data splitting. Am I correct?

Comment: You're right, my mistake.

Comment: I'll just leave this here as a slightly relevant link: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14099/using-k-fold-cross-validation-for-time-series-model-selection

Comment: Hello, did you find an answer to this / what did you end up doing ?